Можно ли использовать Win32 API НЕ в VisualStudio?
Я пишу код в Dev-C++ и заметно привык к этой программе. На VisualStudio переходить не хочу. лично для меня нынешняя программа гораздо удобнее. Но вот сейчас мне понадобилась возможность взаимодействовать с системой. В общем плане. Он использования и создания файлов, и вплоть до управления самой ос и установленной на нем программами. Нашел инфу о том, что для этого отлично подходит win32 api от Майкрософт. Но зайдя на их сайт, я увидел что они не дают никаких инструкций о том, как win32 api использовать в средах разработки помимо visual studio. Более того, я не заметил даже намека на то, можно ли так вообще. Хотя может это я слепой. Читал я их сайт в 2 ночи и уже дико хотел спать. На случай если win32 api можно использовать только в VS спрошу. Есть ли какие нибудь альтернативы?

"Читал я их сайт в 2 ночи и уже дико хотел спать." - да, явно стоит перечитать на свежую голову. WinApi используют вообще все программы, которые работают на Windows, в том числе и те, что вы писали в Dev-C++.

Win API можно использовать только в Windows, а уж какой компилятор вы для этого используете — десятое дело...

@user7860670 не все

@andreymal хм, программа по ссылке под категорию "не все" никак не подходит

https://sourceforge.net/projects/devpaks/files/Win32%20API/

Короткий ответ: Да! Можно.
Системные библиотеки Windows API, построены на языке c, и с++, что говорит о том, что вы можете их использовать где угодно, и как вам угодно, и это не имеет отношения никакого к линкеру, и библиотекам импорта.
Вы можете под каким либо компилятором найти и использовать представленный им API для работы с Windows API, или пойти другим путем, динамической загрузкой библиотек, что даст возможность в райтайме загружать библиотеки, и обращаться к их функциям, это называется динамическое связывание, т.е. в райтайме.
Для этого необходимо читать документацию, и пользоваться представленными возможностями операционной системы, единственное что необходимо будет связать статически с библиотекой kernel32.
Остальные функции обычно расположены в user32 и других, о которых также можно узнать из документации.
